# Apache Beam in Python, error with beam.io.TextFileSource

Tags: python, apache-beam

I'm trying to run the code in the Data Science on GCP repo and keep hitting an error in the Beam code.

This is the line that gives an error:
beam.Read(beam.io.TextFileSource('airports.csv.gz')

Here's the error I'm getting:
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'TextFileSource'

Here's the complete file:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/data-science-on-gcp/blob/master/04_streaming/simulate/df01.py

Does anyone know how to get this working, or what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Google Dataflow is migrating to the Apache Beam standard which means you should be using [apache_beam.io.textio.ReadFromText](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/pydoc/0.6.0/apache_beam.io.html#module-apache_beam.io.textio).  The standard is still evolving so it's best to consult the [Release Notes](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/release-notes/release-notes-python) whenever you upgrade the package.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are using an older version of apache-beam/cloud-dataflow.

Do:

`pip freeze | grep dataflow`

When I do this, I get:

`google-cloud-dataflow==0.4.3`

If your version you get is older, try:

`pip install google-cloud-dataflow`

and repeat the pip freeze command.  If you keep getting an older version, then you are in Python library hell and I suggest using virtualenv to ensure that you are using the latest version of all packages ...

Comment: Thanks, Lak. The version of dataflow that I'm using is newer:
google-cloud-dataflow==0.5.5

Perhaps the SDK changed because I can't find the TextFileSource method in the docs. I tried extracting the .gz file and using the ReadFromText method but hit other errors. I'll check out virtualenv and try running that.

Comment: I am also using google-cloud-dataflow==0.6.0 and the script df03.py failed.I am wondering if Lan will review the codes with the new module apache_beam.io.gcp

Comment: Sorry, I changed the code to use beam.io.ReadFromText but seems I missed a couple of places.  I've made changes to df03.py df04.py and df06.py and checked them in. It should work properly now.